# "set up a meeting (schedule)" vs "decide on a meeting (schedule)" (or "arrange")?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I'm trying to write a sample Business English conversation prompt. The situation is that the students will arrange a meeting with each other, and we want them to think of their own answers/available time and day.

With this in mind, which would be the most natural way to express this in the imperative form?

1. **Set up** the meeting day and time / **Set up** the day and the time of the meeting
2. **Decide on** the meeting schedule / **Decide on** the meeting day and time
3. **Arrange** the meeting schedule

I'm leaning towards #2 here, but do you have any advice on how to make it sound more natural?

Comment: Why not just say "Schedule the meeting"? *Schedule* is a verb on its own.

Comment: “A meeting schedule” suggests regularity, such as the second Tuesday of each month.  Perhaps: Arrange a meeting. Be sure to specify the day, date, and time.

Comment: @Xanne There's a difference between "schedule" as a noun and verb. The noun does suggest regularity, but the verb has no such connotation.